# Error message "NoMethodError in Posts#new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making a simple bbs by Ruby on Rails, sorry in Japanese.
I just got this error message

> "NoMethodError in Posts#new"
>
> Showing /Users/igarashinobuo/portfolio/cpmybbs/app/views/posts/new.html.erb where line #7 raised:
>
> undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass
>
> ```
>   </div>
>   <div class="mt-10 pd-20">
>     <% @topic.posts.order(:id).each.with_index(1) do |post , idx| %>
>       <p>
>         <%= idx %>
>         <%= post.name %>
> ```

This error happens, when I wanted to access 'http://localhost:3002/topics/22/posts/new'. 
22 is the number of post.
New page is for the page of micropost.

```
# app/views/posts/new.html.erb
<div class="text-center bg-light font-weight-normal pt-3">
  <a href=/topics>Chatty</a>
</div>
  <div class="text-center pb-20 mt-10">
  </div>
  <div class="mt-10 pd-20">
    <% @topic.posts.order(:id).each.with_index(1) do |post , idx| %>
      <p>
        <%= idx %>
        <%= post.name %>
        <%= post.body %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="newpost my-auto mb-60">
    <h4>新規書き込み</h4>
    <%= form_for @post, url: topic_posts_path(@topic) do |f| %>
      <div class="post_area">
        <p><%= f.text_field :name %></p>
        <p><%= f.label :name %></p>
        <p><%= f.text_field :name %></p>
        <p><%= f.label :body %></p>
        <p><%= f.text_area :body %></p>
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

# posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = @topic.posts.build(set_topic)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to new_topic_post_path(@topic)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_topic
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id, :title])
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:name, :body)
  end
end

# error log
app/views/posts/new.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_posts_new_html_erb__4195515470978617912_70184702044840'
Started GET "/topics/22/posts/new" for ::1 at 2019-02-06 11:52:00 +0900
Processing by PostsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"topic_id"=>"22"}
  Rendering posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass):
    4:   <div class="text-center pb-20 mt-10">
    5:   </div>
    6:   <div class="mt-10 pd-20">
    7:     <% @topic.posts.order(:id).each.with_index(1) do |post , idx| %>
    8:       <p>
    9:         <%= idx %>
   10:         <%= post.name %
```

Could you help me kindly debug?

Comment: Do you use `set_topic` for setting `@topic` in your new action? the most simple reason might be that the variable hasn't be defined and hence returns nil when invoking it.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Is that inside new action of PostsController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some changes to the controller:

- add `set_topic` before filter, to find `@topic` for every action
- change `set_topic` a bit, for some reasons you try to find topic by
  `params[:topic_id, :title]`, it is invalid way to access hash value
- use `post_params` to build a new post

Result:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_topic

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = @topic.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to new_topic_post_path(@topic)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_topic
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:name, :body)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you again. I really appreciate you, Vailisa.